# Que pongo en la parte de currently?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

estoy recién aprendiendo a programar en kotlin y también a desarrollar en android studio.

En una app de clima que estoy haciendo quiero poner una barra de notificaciones para mostrar la temperatura en las notificaciones. Se que necesito de condición a currently para que funcione lo de obtener la temperatura, pero cuando quiero llamar a la función no se que poner entre los paréntesis

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    getWeather()
    createNotificationChannel()
    sendNotification()   <-------En los parentesis de aqui me da el error, y no se que debería poner
    notificacionNotification()
}

private fun createNotificationChannel(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        val name = getString(R.string.notification_title)
        val descriptionText = "DESCRIPCION NOTIFICACION"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply{
            description = descriptionText
        }
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    }
private fun sendNotification(currently: Currently?){

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, 0)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_weather_status)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
        .setContentText("${currently?.temperature?.roundToInt()}")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)){
        notify(notificationId, builder.build())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo supongo que tenes que pasarle el valor que devuelve la función getWeather().
Quedaría así:

```
...
val currently = getWeather()
createNotificationChannel()
sendNotification(currently)
...
```

Si recién estás aprendiendo te recomiendo que crees tu propio código en vez copiar uno que después no sabes lo que hace.